# How to pass get images in homepage also in portfolio page?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am using acf repeater and used subfield as image. Uploaded images in through homepage admin, but how can i show same images in other page?

Homepage Acf code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="journal-block">
        <div class="row">

            <?php if( have_rows('gaimages') ): ?>

                <?php
                    while( have_rows('gaimages') ) :
                        the_row(); 
                        $image = get_sub_field('images');
                        $text = get_sub_field('text12');
                        $text11 = "Hai Tst";
                ?>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="journal-info">
                        <a href="blog-single.html">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>">
                        </a>

                        <div class="journal-txt">
                            <h4><a href="blog-single.html">
                                <?php echo $text; ?>
                            </a></h4>
                            <p class="separator">To an English person, it will seem like simplified English</p>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the code you are using to display on the home page.  Very likely just need to pass an ID when displaying on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that you've set images in homepage admin, so I guess you're using static page as homepage... In such case you can use this code to show these images anywhere else on your site:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="journal-block">
        <div class="row">

            <?php if ( have_rows( 'gaimages', get_option('page_on_front') ) ): ?>

                <?php
                    while ( have_rows( 'gaimages', get_option('page_on_front') ) ) :
                        the_row(); 
                        $image = get_sub_field('images');
                        $text = get_sub_field('text12');
                        $text11 = "Hai Tst";
                ?>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="journal-info">
                        <a href="blog-single.html">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>">
                        </a>

                        <div class="journal-txt">
                            <h4><a href="blog-single.html">
                                <?php echo $text; ?>
                            </a></h4>
                            <p class="separator">To an English person, it will seem like simplified English</p>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```